# Debugging CloudFront Signed URLs using Trusted Signers and Node.js SDK

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-cloudfront, aws-sdk-nodejs

AWS can have annoyingly few details about errors and I've found myself stuck without a clear path forward.

I have code in my Node.js app that seems to be generating both signed URLs and signed cookies, but neither are allowing me to access resources on my private CloudFront distribution. This is the 403 response I get, instead:

```
<Error>
  <Code>InvalidKey</Code>
  <Message>Unknown Key</Message>
</Error>
```

My solution is spread across two AWS accounts.

- Master account

  - S3 bucket holding my private content
  - Private CloudFront distribution pointed at the S3 bucket
  - [Public key](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/home#publickey:) paired with the private key used in Elastic Beanstalk
  - Route53 record with custom subdomains for all distributions (master & members) & API

    - privatedistro.mydomain.com
    - reactapp.mydomain.com
    - api.mydomain.com
- Member account(s)

  - Node.js-based API running on Elastic Beanstalk (this does the signing & returns cookies on login)
  - S3 bucket holding front-end react app
  - Public CloudFront distribution to serve React app
  - *I tried adding a public key to CloudFront here and using its ID too*

The key pair ID and private key are configured as environment variables using [the Elastic Beanstalk console](https://region.console.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/home#/environment/configuration). Here's my code (it's executing without errors):

```
const cloudFront =
  sails.config.custom.cloudfront.keyPairId &&
  sails.config.custom.cloudfront.privateKey &&
  new AWS.CloudFront.Signer(
    sails.config.custom.cloudfront.keyPairId,
    sails.config.custom.cloudfront.privateKey.replace(/\\n/g, '\n')  // environment variables passed through Elastic Beanstalk get altered
  );


        // Set Cookies after successful verification
        const policy = JSON.stringify({
          Statement: [
            {
              Resource: 'https://privatedistro.mydomain.com/*',
              Condition: {
                DateLessThan: {
                  'AWS:EpochTime':
                    Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000) + 60 * 60 * 24 // Current Time in UTC + time in seconds, (1 day)
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        });
        cookie = cloudFront.getSignedCookie({ policy });

        this.res.cookie(
          'CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id',
          cookie['CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id'],
          {
            domain: '.mydomain.com',
            path: '/',
            httpOnly: true
          }
        );

        this.res.cookie(
          'CloudFront-Expires',
          Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000) + 60 * 60 * 24, // Current Time in UTC + time in seconds, (60 * 60 * 24 = 1 day)
          {
            domain: '.mydomain.com',
            path: '/',
            httpOnly: true
          }
        );

        this.res.cookie(
          'CloudFront-Signature',
          cookie['CloudFront-Signature'],
          {
            domain: '.mydomain.com',
            path: '/',
            httpOnly: true
          }
        );
```

The cookies that are returned look like this:

- CloudFront-Expires=1593487645
- CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id=K48HZXSAAM76P   *(not EC2/IAM: key-0847abcde123456)*
- CloudFront-Signature=*[345-character string ending in __]*

[image]

In the *Default Cache Behavior Settings* of my private distribution, I've selected *Yes* for *Restrict Viewer Access*, selected both self and selected accounts as *Trusted Signers* and entered the 13-digit number of the member account in the *AWS Account Numbers* field. Before I turned on *Restrict Viewer Access*, everything was being served nicely, so I don't think there's an issue with other parts of the CloudFront setup.

Any ideas where I went wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key you're using looks incorrect, to work with CloudFront signed URL, you need to use CloudFront key pair, not the EC2 one, mentioned in below doc:

[Generate Signed URL CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-trusted-signers.html)

The CloudFront key-ID looks more like a Access key of IAM.

Comment: Thanks! I completely missed that CloudFront handled it's own keys. For others in the future, although the docs said that 4096 bit key length was supported, CloudFront threw an error when I tried to add it. A 2048 bit length key pair was accepted. I replaced the key ID (K48HZXSAAM76P) and private key in my Elastic Beanstalk environment variables, but I'm still getting the same InvalidKey error...

Comment: The docs also say "CloudFront must be aware of the active key pair. After you create a key pair, there can be a short period of time before CloudFront is aware that the key pair exists."

So, I'll try again later today.

Comment: I should clarify; I added the public key in three places and got three different IDs. None of them are giving me access to the private distro.  (1) I logged in as the root user of the master account and went to https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home#/security_credentials. The CloudFront Key Pairs tab gave me a ID that looks like APKAIAXXXXXXXXXXXXGA. (2) I used an IAM user on the master account to reach https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/home#publickey: and got an ID like K48HZXSAAM76P. (3) I used the same user and URL in the member account and got a similar ID.

Comment: You just need the Access key listed when you move to console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home#/security_credentials , when you create a key pair, it lets you download the Private key which you need to use, you don't need any sort of IAM access key/secret key. Only two keys can be active at a time for CloudFront use.

Comment: One step forward. After waiting a while, the longer ID from the master account did get CloudFront to change its behavior. Unfortunately, its another error message: AccessDenied. I'll see if I can debug that tomorrow.

Thanks!

Comment: Stuck again. I've gone through every item in the troubleshooting guide and I seem to be set up correctly. Perhaps I need to open a new question for the AccessDenied error...
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-rest-api-cloudfront-error-403/